# I tried creating the equivalent of this in Java, but I am facing NullPointerException the moment I enter the first name

Tags: java, c

This is my first question ever, so please be easy on me for formatting. I tried searching a lot for the answer but couldn't get what I wanted

This is the C program and is working as desired

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int i,n;
    struct student {
        char name[20];
        int roll;
        int age;
        float marks;
    };
    printf("Enter number of students\n");
    scanf(" %d", &n);
    struct student a[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        printf("Enter details of student %d\n",(i+1));
        printf("Name : ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", &a[i].name);
        printf("Roll number: ");
        scanf(" %d", &a[i].roll);
        printf("Age : ");
        scanf(" %d", &a[i].age);
        printf("Marks : ");
        scanf(" %f", &a[i].marks);
    }
    printf("\n%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s\n\n", "Name", "Roll no", "Age", "Marks");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%-20s%-20d%-20d%-20.2f\n", a[i].name, a[i].roll, a[i].age, a[i].marks);
    return 0;
}
```

To write this in Java, I created a Student class first

```
public class Student {
    public String name;
    public int roll,age;
    public float marks;
}
```

And then a TestStructure class to make the program

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestStructure {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int i,n;
        System.out.println("Enter number of students");
        n=sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine(); //To consume new line
        Student[] a=new Student[n];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
            System.out.printf("Enter details of student %d\n",(i+1));
            System.out.printf("Name : ");
            a[i].name=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.printf("Roll number: ");
            a[i].roll=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.printf("Age : ");
            a[i].age=sc.nextInt();
            System.out.printf("Marks : ");
            a[i].marks=sc.nextFloat();
            sc.nextLine(); //To consume new line
        }
        sc.close();
        System.out.printf("\n%-20s%-20s%-20s%-20s\n\n", "Name", "Roll no", "Age", "Marks");
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            System.out.printf("%-20s%-20d%-20d%-20.2f\n", a[i].name, a[i].roll, a[i].age, a[i].marks);
    }
}
```

But I get NullPointerException as soon as I enter the first name

Comment: change &a[i].name to a[i].name  and scanf %..s to %s

Comment: But the C program is working. Also wouldn't that restrict me to one word only?

Comment: You have to allocate memory - the Student class - using 'new' keyword. Add following definition "a[i] = new Student();" in the for statement before you use an a[i] as a Student object itself then your exception will be gone..

Comment: add this in for loop. a[i] = new Student() ;

Comment: Thank you so much @tommybee. It worked. Also on a slight different note, is there any advantage or disadvantage of using a class as a structure?

Comment: @Parvinder, dear. it's long story. The java and C++ are described as a OOP language. you'd better find  the weak and strong point of it.